# How do I bind a label to a ViewModel store with a Single record

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I am using the example Admin dashboard in order to create a frame for an application and one of the things I am doing is wiring up the header of the dashboard.

The code below is the View and the Store from the ViewModel, the store is getting data, I have verified it by using this line of code in a render listener to verify data is populating. `this.getViewModel().data`

The dashboard has the following code in the View, how do I bind this record  and the stores 'name' field to the tbtext component shown below?  Do I need to wrap the header bar in a form in order to populate the record first?  Does the Bind call need to define the zero based record in some way?  Or is the record possibly not loading in time to render based on the way the store loads from a ViewModel (which would make no sense)??

The ellipses are being used to remove irrelevant code:

```
Ext.define('BbgApp.view.main.MainView', {
extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
alias: 'widget.mainview',

requires: [
    'BbgApp.view.main.MainViewViewModel',
    'BbgApp.view.main.MainViewViewController',
    'BbgApp.view.main.MainContanierWrap',
    'Ext.form.Panel',
    'Ext.toolbar.Toolbar',
    'Ext.Img',
    'Ext.toolbar.TextItem',
    'Ext.toolbar.Separator',
    'Ext.list.Tree',

],

controller: 'mainmainview',
viewModel: {
    type: 'mainmainview'
},
flex: 1,
itemId: 'mainView',
layout: 'border',
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        region: 'north',
        cls: 'sencha-dash-dash-headerbar',
        height: 100,
        itemId: 'headerBar',
        items: [
            ...
            {
                xtype: 'tbseparator',
                flex: 1
            },
            {
                xtype: 'tbtext',
                text: 'Bob Wazowski',
                bind: {
                    text: '{userStore.name}'
                },
                reference: 'tbname'
            }, ...
```

Here is the ViewModel code:

```
Ext.define('BbgApp.view.main.MainViewViewModel', {
extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
alias: 'viewmodel.mainmainview',

requires: [
    'Ext.data.Store',
    'Ext.data.field.Field',
    'Ext.data.proxy.Rest',
    'Ext.data.reader.Json'
],

stores: {
    userStore: {
        pageSize: 0,
        remoteFilter: true,
        remoteSort: true,
        autoLoad: true,
        fields: [
            {
                name: 'id'
            },
            {
                name: 'name'
            }            ],
        proxy: {
            type: 'rest',
            noCache: false,
            url: '/api/user',
            appendId: false,
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'data'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

In your first block of code, you could be missing this part (before the `items` property):

```
viewModel: {
    xclass: 'BbgApp.view.main.MainViewViewModel'
},
```

In other words, set the view's `viewmodel`.

Comment: I include all that in the View, I just did not add it here in order to not possibly over muddy the water.   I will add it into the question if it helps